# How do I check to see if a mouse click is within a rectangle for each rectangle in this pygame program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to make a pygame program to see if a user clicked on a rectangle, and if so, to change that rectangle's colour.

Here's my initial code to draw the screen:

```
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()

size_x = 650
size_y = 550
bkg_colour = 0, 0, 0
white = 255, 255, 255
colour = 0, 130, 90
position_x, position_y = 70, 100
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((size_x, size_y))

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        screen.fill(bkg_colour)

        for x in range(-50, 500, position_x + 20):
            for y in range(-50, 400, position_y + 20):
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, colour, (position_x + x, position_y + y, position_x, position_y), 0)

        pygame.display.flip()
```

What I tried doing was using pygame.Rect and collisionpoint like this:

```
for x in range(-50, 500, position_x + 20):
            for y in range(-50, 400, position_y + 20):
                rect_size = pygame.Rect(position_x + x, position_y + y, position_x, position_y)
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, colour, rect_size, 0)

if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            click = rect_size.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())

            if click == 1:
                print("Clicked")
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, rect_size, 0)

pygame.display.flip()
```

But what it does is only work for the last drawn rectangle on the screen.
How do I make it work for every rectangle on the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rect_size` holds one value at a time, and you override it again and again until it holds the last rectangle.

you want to hold a list of the rectangles and check collision with all of them.

instead of

```
rect_size = pygame.Rect(position_x + x, position_y + y, position_x, position_y)
```

you want to do something like:

```
rect_sizes.append(pygame.Rect(position_x + x, position_y + y, position_x, position_y))
```

and then iterate `rect_sizes` and check collision with each one.

```
rect_sizes = []
for x in range(-50, 500, position_x + 20):
    for y in range(-50, 400, position_y + 20):
        rect_size = pygame.Rect(position_x + x, position_y + y, position_x, position_y)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, colour, rect_size, 0)
        rect_sizes.append(rect_size)

if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    for rect_size in rect_sizes:
        click = rect_size.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())

        if click == 1:
            print("Clicked")
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, rect_size, 0)
```